# How do I make an object move in the direction that it's facing in ursina?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina

I want to be able to make an object move forward in ursina, but can't figure out how.

I tried the .forward method but that only gives the direction and I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Do `entity.position += entity.forward` to move it forward, while taking rotation into account. If you don't need to account for rotation, `entity.z += 1` would work too.

Example where we move forward while the w key is pressed:

```py
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()
entity = Entity(model='cube')

def update():
    entity.position += entity.forward * time.dt * held_keys['w']

app.run()
```

Comment: Here's a video that  show how it can be done: https://youtube.com/shorts/Oo_APxhG27U?feature=share

Comment: I need it to work without any keys being held. Thank you anyways though

Comment: If so, just remove the `* held_keys['w']`